# Atom to RSS Conversion Tool in Python

Tags: python, rss, atom-feed

This post is really going to show my lack of knowledge with the two formats, but does there exist a tool that will convert an Atom document into an RSS document?

I'm hoping there is a pre-existing library in Python that I can use but obviously if it's not too much of a hassle, I don't mind writing it myself.

Comment: To clarify, you want to convert to RSS 2.0 (which can contain most of the same info), not convert to RSS 1.0 (and throw away a lot of stuff), right?

Comment: To give you the full story, I'm trying to convert a Weebly blog into a Wordpress blog. I found one hacky solution here http://www.fleecefun.com/how-to-convert-weebly-to-wordpress.html.  This solves the problem of only having a few posts in the normal weebly rss feed by using Google Reader but leaves me with an Atom file.  I'm trying to google around right now but my assumption is that imports on WP will take RSS 2.0.

Comment: I believe WP can work with AtomPub, which means the simplest way to do this may be to just submit the Weebly posts via AtomPub. And that's assuming Weebly isn't one of the hundreds of formats that WP can import directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything that does it in one step (you've tried searching [The Cheese Shop](http://pypi.python.org), right?), but you can do it in two steps pretty easily.

I've used [feedparser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser/5.1.2) to parse both Atom and RSS (both 1.0 and 2.0), and it does an amazing job at handling all of the annoying edge cases, including common but not-quite-standard uses, broken encodings, etc.

And then generating the RSS should be the easy part—there are probably lots of libs for that, but I don't really have one to recommend.

Meanwhile, this looks interesting: [interssection](https://github.com/narfdotpl/interssection) lets you read multiple Atom and RSS feeds, and do set operations on them, and export the result to a single feed in any format. Presumably it would work just fine if the "multiple" feeds were a list of 1… The problem is that "at the moment" (and that was written 2 years ago), Atom 1.0 is the only supported output…

Comment: I haven't tried searching the cheese shop (this is actually the first time I've heard of it.)  I was looking at feedparser but wasn't entirely sure how to convert it's results into RSS.  I wrote it off but I'll look into it again and investigate the second step.

Comment: This solution in combination with PyRSS2Gen seems like it's going to work.  Appreciate the help. http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html

Comment: Glad it worked. If it takes more than a few lines of code to integrate `feedparser` (or `interssection` or whatever you used) with `PyRSS2Gen`, you might want to consider pasting it on ActiveState's recipes, putting it on github, and/or packaging it up as a PyPI project with the right dependencies, so in the future someone else can just `pip install atomtorss`.